# How to mock each selectors return value? jest

Tags: react-redux, jestjs

I have already tried different approaches to mocking selectors, but they always show `undefined` when I try to log them in the actual component. I have tried some of the suggested ways to achieve it, but some were just a bit far from my objective.

Expected values for `loading` in **Main.tsx** should be `boolean`

Somebody knows how to achieve this? Related links: [Is there a way to properly...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55696552/is-there-a-way-to-properly-mock-reselect-selectors-for-unit-testing), [useSelector of Undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60668240/useselector-of-undefined),

---

**Main.test.tsx**

```
import * as accountingSelectors from 'src/redux/limited/accounting/user/selectors';

jest.mock('src/redux/limited/accounting/user/selectors');

describe('...', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.spyOn(accountingSelectors, 'fetchingSelector').mockReturnValue(true);
    });
});
```

**Main.tsx**

```
const Main = () => {
  const loading = useSelector(fetchingSelector);

  // always return "undefined" here when I run the test.
  console.log('line 42 ~ Main ~ loading', loading); 
  
  ...
});
```

**selectors.ts**

```
export const fetchingSelector = createSelector(
  (state) => state,
  ({ data }) => {
    return data.fetching;
  }
);
```